# Running Dart Sass on Gulp or Grunt

Tags: sass, gulp, gruntjs

Ruby Sass is going away (unless a new maintainer takes it on) and is being replaced by a Dart implementation, according to this post:

[Announcing Dart Sass](http://sass.logdown.com/posts/1022316-announcing-dart-sass)

Does anyone know if there are plugins already in progress for Gulp or Grunt?

Answer (score 3):

I was working on a personal project several months ago and wanted dart-sass with gulp so I made my own rudimentary function for until someone else came along and made something better. I don't remember which version dart-sass was on at the time, but here's the function anyway. It just sits right in the gulpfile.

```
function sassify(options) {
  return through.obj(function (file, enc, cb) {
    options = options || {};
    options.file = file.path;
    // if (file.sourceMap) {
      // options.sourceMap = true;
      // options.outFile = output.path('css');
    // }
    sass.render(options, function (err, result) {
      if (err) {
        console.error("Sass Error: " + err.message);
      }
      else {
        file.contents = result.buffer;
        // if (file.sourceMap) {
          // applySourceMap(file, result.map);
        // }
      }
      cb(err, file);
    });
  });
}
```

At the time, dart-sass didn't have source maps yet so I just plugged that stuff in and commented it out for when they do.
I used the function this way:

```
gulp.task('build:css', function () {
  gulp.src(input.sass)
    // .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(sassify())
    // .pipe(sourcemaps.write(output.path('cssmap')))
    .pipe(concat(output.path('css')))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('.'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Using dart-sass from gulp should be straightforward:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/dart-sass#from-npm

```
npm install dart-sass

var sass = require('dart-sass');
sass.render(...)
```

Don't know about grunt though.

Comment: I'm not sure it's that easy, because the purpose of Gulp would be to use streams, yes? But it seems like render() and renderSync() don't return a useable stream, but perhaps a Buffer instead.

Answer (score 0):

Since the news of Ruby Sass' deprecation and first official release of Dart Sass, I recently contributed the [`grunt-dart-sass`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-dart-sass) package to the npm registry, and it looks like another user has contributed [`gulp-dart-sass`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-dart-sass). Since these are user-contributed packages, they were not created by the makers of Dart Sass themselves but still interface with the Dart Sass API. Hopefully, the [`grunt-contrib-sass`](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-sass) project will also upgrade their package to use Dart Sass soon enough.